# How do I open a FLA File without Adobe Animate?

Tags: flash, adobe, fla

I have a sprite pack which is a .fla file. I want to open this file without paying money for a program. I have already tried to open it by installing Macromedia Flash 8. Macromedia Flash 8 is a 32-bit app, which newer versions of MacOS would not support. Is there any program that can open this .fla file. I have MacOS Ventura currently. I have tried using .fla viewers online, but the result is a bunch of text.

Comment: Simply put, you don't. **SWF** is *relatively* open format and there always was (and even now is) a bunch of projectors and plugins to support it. On the other hand, **FLA** is a Flash Authoring IDE project source file, and I don't remember anyone bothering building an alternative authoring environment. I have no solution for your problem, but here's a hint: you can set up a virtual machine on your MacOS and have a pocket Windows (XP or such) to run the obsolete software you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You just ***can't***.

Trust me.

FLAs only open in any version of Adobe Animate. This includes the versions previously named Flash (versions 1-let's say 15), although that depends on the version of the program the FLA requires.

Do note that Flash CS5.5, version 11.5, opens all FLAs with some issues. Seeing that you are using Ventura, you have no choice but to get Adobe Animate.